# Plotting points on Australia Map in Python

Tags: python, geopandas

I have the following pandas df

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Define the list of cities and their latitudes/longitudes
cities = ['Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane', 'Perth', 'Adelaide', 'Gold Coast', 'Newcastle', 'Canberra', 'Wollongong', 'Sunshine Coast', 'Hobart', 'Alice Springs']
lats = [-33.865143, -37.813629, -27.469771, -31.953512, -34.928499, -28.016666, -32.916668, -35.282001, -34.4278, -26.6500, -42.8821, -23.6970]
longs = [151.209900, 144.963165, 153.025124, 115.857048, 138.600739, 153.399994, 151.750000, 149.128998, 150.8931, 153.0500, 147.3272, 133.8836]

# Generate a random priority for each city between 1 and 5
priority = np.random.randint(1, 6, size=len(cities))

# Create the DataFrame with the city data
data = {'cityname': cities,
        'lats': lats,
        'longs': longs,
        'priority': priority}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I got the shapefile from https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files/STE_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA2020.zip

And the rest of the code are,

```
# Load the shapefile of Australia
australia = gpd.read_file('STE_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA2020/STE_2021_AUST_GDA2020.shp')

# Define the CRS of the shapefile manually
australia.crs = 'epsg:7844'

# Create a GeoDataFrame from the DataFrame of cities
gdf_cities = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longs, df.lats))

# Set the CRS of the GeoDataFrame to EPSG 7844
# https://epsg.io/7844
gdf_cities.crs = 'epsg:7844'

# Reproject the GeoDataFrame of cities to match the CRS of the shapefile
gdf_cities = gdf_cities.to_crs(australia.crs)

# Perform a spatial join to link the cities to their corresponding polygons in the shapefile
gdf_cities = gpd.sjoin(gdf_cities, australia, predicate='within')

# Set up the plot
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# Plot the cities colored by priority
sns.scatterplot(ax=ax, data=gdf_cities, x='longs', y='lats', hue='priority', s=100, legend='full')

# Add the shapefile of Australia as a background map
australia.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey', edgecolor='white')

# Set the plot title and axis labels
plt.title('Cities in Australia')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

I could not figure out why the points are not plotted correctly on the Australian map.  Can someone review where I am doing it wrong and let me know how to fix?  E.g. Alice Springs is in the middle of Australia.  Thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: it looks like you're plotting "australia" after the scatter plot. hence why the coastal cities are just barely visible and inland cities are not shown at all

Comment: so, how do I fixed this?  I was suspecting I did something wrong with the crs

Comment: In general, things you plot later in your code will be on top of things you plot earlier. This can be changed manually using zorder as in the accepted answer, or you could just plot the points after the shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `zorder` parameter to plot your scatter points on top of the Australian map:

```
# Plot the cities colored by priority
sns.scatterplot(ax=ax, data=gdf_cities, x='longs', y='lats', hue='priority', s=100, legend='full', zorder=2)

# Add the shapefile of Australia as a background map
australia.plot(ax=ax, color='lightgrey', edgecolor='white', zorder=1)
```